# Does git checkout -B perform a reset?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

I have branch called `shared` that is shared amongst other developers. I work off of a `feature` branch. Whilst on my `feature` branch, I ran `git checkout -B shared`, and got the following message:

```
Switched to and reset branch 'shared'
Your branch and 'origin/shared' have diverged,
and have 6 and 126 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

I pulled and resolved the conflicts and suddenly realized that my `shared` branch had all of my changes from my `feature` branch. My questions are:

1. How did this happen exactly?
2. Looking at the docs it says that the branch is reset when running checkout with the `-B` flag:

   > If `-B` is given, `<new_branch>` is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is reset.

   Last time I checked, running reset on a shared branch was dangerous. Or does 'reset' have a different meaning, in this context?

Comment: You basically force updated `shared` to point to `feature`, the modified it further.  Recovering via the reflog seems appropriate.

Comment: if all you want is to get your `shared` branch back in line with `origin/shared`, just do `git checkout shared && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: @kdopen your suggestion above will just make my local ``shared`` branch match the remote. And then I can just merge in ``feature`` like normal? Would the last command be ``git reset --hard origin/shared``

Comment: @kdopen Nice one. Your fix undoes both the reset of `shared` to `feature` and the premature merge of `origin/shared` into what was basically `feature`. After your fix, we're left off just as we would be if @Jeff had run `git checkout shared` followed by `git pull origin/shared` in the first place, which is exactly what he wanted to do. Beautiful. Now he can run `git merge feature` and he's ready to push.

Comment: @Jeff yes sorry. The last command should have been `git reset --hard origin/shared`. Force of habit to reset to master - I usually only push master and develop,

Comment: Anyone want it as an alternative answer? Shaun's is excellent (and accepted).

Comment: @kdopen Is the `fetch` necessary? I don't think it is. Also, is the `--hard` necessary? Couldn't we just run `git checkout shared` followed by `git reset origin/shared` and be in the same boat. We just need to get `shared` back to the `origin/shared` ref, and I don't think we're worried about the content of the working dir (ergo no `--hard`). What you suggested works, though I think it could be simpler and still meet the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer

**Sometimes**. `git checkout -B <branch_name>` performs a reset if `branch_name` already exists.

## Details

> Why did this happen, exactly?

As you indicated, `git checkout -B <shared>` resets `shared` to the `HEAD` commit and checks out `shared`. What does this do, exactly?

- Point `shared` at your *current HEAD commit*. **(This answers your first question).**
- Empty everything you recently added out of your index.
- Checkout `shared`.

In other words, you reset `shared` to match `feature`. Here's an example that shows how you were before the `checkout -B`:

```
 > git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph

 * d0d0d0d (HEAD, feature) Some commit message.
 * e0e0e0e Some commit message.
 * f0f0f0f Some commit message.
 * g0g0g0g Some commit message. 
 * h0h0h0h Some commit message. 
 * i0i0i0i Some commit message. 
 |     * z0z0z0z (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * y0y0y0y (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * x0x0x0x (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     ---- 120 more commits ----
 |     * w0w0w0w (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * v0v0v0v (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * u0u0u0u (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |   /   
 | /     
 * a0a0a0a (shared) Some commit message.
 * b0b0b0b Some commit message.
 * c0c0c0c Some commit message.
```

And here's how you were after the `checkout -B`:

```
 > git checkout -B shared
 > git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph

 * d0d0d0d (HEAD, feature, shared) Some commit message.
 * e0e0e0e Some commit message.
 * f0f0f0f Some commit message.
 * g0g0g0g Some commit message. 
 * h0h0h0h Some commit message. 
 * i0i0i0i Some commit message. 
 |     * z0z0z0z (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * y0y0y0y (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * x0x0x0x (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     ---- 120 more commits ----
 |     * w0w0w0w (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * v0v0v0v (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * u0u0u0u (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |   /   
 | /     
 * a0a0a0a Some commit message.
 * b0b0b0b Some commit message.
 * c0c0c0c Some commit message.
```

`shared` will now have all the changes from `feature`, your `shared will have 6 different commits that`origin/shared`, and likewise it will have 126 different commits than yours.

> Does 'reset' have a different meaning, in this context?

Reset has the same meaning as it always does. You basically did the following:

```
git checkout shared
git reset --mixed feature
```

## A Good Fix

> All I wanted to do was pull down shared and merge in feature. Is there a way to undo this?

@kdopen's comment suggests a good fix. Though both the `fetch` and the `--hard` option on `reset` are optional (see comments on the question for details). Here's my modified fix.

```
git checkout shared 
git reset origin/shared
```

That should land you in this position, from which you can merge in your `feature` branch as intended.

```
 * d0d0d0d (feature) Some commit message.
 * e0e0e0e Some commit message.
 * f0f0f0f Some commit message.
 * g0g0g0g Some commit message. 
 * h0h0h0h Some commit message. 
 * i0i0i0i Some commit message. 
 |     * z0z0z0z (HEAD, shared, origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * y0y0y0y (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * x0x0x0x (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     ---- 120 more commits ----
 |     * w0w0w0w (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * v0v0v0v (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |     * u0u0u0u (origin/shared) Some commit message.
 |   /   
 | /     
 * a0a0a0a Some commit message.
 * b0b0b0b Some commit message.
 * c0c0c0c Some commit message.
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I intended to do. All I wanted to do was pull down ``shared`` and merge in ``feature``. Is there a way to undo this? Git revert maybe?

Comment: Since you moved `shared` via a `reset` command, you'll want to put it back where it came from with another `reset` command.

Comment: If I push ``shared`` as is, will it mess up those who also work off this branch?

Comment: @Jeff Yes. You moved the tip of `shared` when you did a reset. So your merge in of `origin/shared` merged into the wrong commit.

Comment: I don't know how to use ``git reset`` to undo this. Maybe I just remove my local ``shared`` branch, re-pull and then merge in ``feature``?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not so sure about deleting your local shared branch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71125/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-jeff).

Answer (score 1):

The default starting position for a new branch (`git checkout -b newbr`) is `HEAD`.

This is also true for the reset action of "create-or-reset" `git checkout -B oldbr`.  So since you were on `feature`, `HEAD` said `feature` which resolved to the ID of the tip-most commit on branch `feature`, which made your existing branch label `shared` point to that same commit.

Fortunately `shared@{1}` will have its previous position, so you can simply `git reset shared@{1}` (if you use csh or tcsh, you must quote the open brace, e.g., `shared@\{1}` or `'shared@{1}'`; not sure about some other shells).

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -b` and `git checkout -B` are used to checkout a (new) branch from a commit. `-B` is used to possibly re-use an existing branch by resetting it or otherwise creating it and `-b` is used to create a new one without the possibility of re-using an existing one.

```
git checkout -B shared
```

is the same thing as

```
git checkout -B shared HEAD
```

and it means

If a branch named `shared` exists, check it out and reset it to `HEAD` (in your case, `HEAD` was the tip of `feature`). If no branch named `shared` exists, create one based on `HEAD`.

What happened: You reset `shared` to `feature` and then pulled in `origin/shared` (and solved the conflicts)